# Pagination PhP gallery (No database)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, fancybox

I'm trying to add pagination to my current PHP gallery and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703618/get-all-photos-from-folder-and-paginate-with-php) is closest thing I've found for help so far. I did a lot of reading and got the code -kinda- working.

Here's the original gallery code

```
$imageFolder = 'img/gallery/FaL/'; 
$pattern = '/[\w-]+.    (jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/'; 
$i = 1; foreach(glob($imageFolder.'*') as $filename){
if(preg_match($pattern, $filename)) {
$filename = basename($filename);
    if ($i % 6 == 1) echo '<div class="row">'; 
$image = '<div class="col-md-2">'; 
$image .= '<a href="'.$imageFolder.$filename.'" class="thumbnail">'; 
$image .= '<img src="'.$imageFolder.$filename.'" alt="" />'; 
$image .= '</a>'; 
$image .= '</div>'; 
echo $image; 
    if ($i % 6 == 0) echo '</div>'; 
$i++; } } if ($i % 6 != 1) echo '</div>';
```

And here is what I currently have for the pagination.

```
$folder = 'img/gallery/FaL/';
$filetype = '*.*';    
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$total = count($files);    
$per_page = 25;    
$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);    
    if(isset($_GET["page"])  && ($_GET["page"] <=$last_page) && ($_GET["page"] > 0) ){
$page = $_GET["page"];
$offset = ($per_page + 1)*($page - 1);      
    }else{
echo "Page out of range showing results for page one";
$page=1;
$offset=0;      
}    
$max = $offset + $per_page;    
    if($max>$total){
$max = $total;
}

//print_r($files);
echo "Processsing page : $page offset: $offset max: $max total: $total last_page: $last_page";        
show_pagination($page, $last_page);        
for($i = $offset; $i< $max; $i++){
    $file = $files[$i];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $path_parts['filename'];       
    if ($i % 6 == 1) echo '<div class="row">';
    $image = '<div class="col-md-2">';
    $image .= '<a href="'.$folder.$filename.'.jpg" class="thumbnail">';
    $image .= '<img src="'.$folder.$filename.'.jpg" alt="" />';
    $image .= '</a>';
    $image .= '</div>';
    echo $image;
    if ($i % 6 == 0) echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}

if ($i % 6 != 1) echo '</div>';   

show_pagination($page, $last_page);

function show_pagination($current_page, $last_page){
echo '<div>';
if( $current_page > 1 ){
    echo ' <a href="?page='.($current_page-1).'"> &lt;&lt;Previous </a> ';
}
if( $current_page < $last_page ){
    echo ' <a href="?page='.($current_page+1).'"> Next&gt;&gt; </a> ';  
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

I made a test gallery page www.htopro.com/tg.php and the pictures are working, my fancybox is working but I can't get it to layout correctly the way the original code did - www.htopro.com/fal.php 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageFolder = $folder
echo  '<div class="row">';
foreach(glob($imageFolder.'*') as $filename){
        $filename = basename($filename);
        $image = '<div class="col-md-2">'; 
        $image .= '<a href="'.$imageFolder.$filename.'" class="thumbnail">'; 
        $image .= '<img src="'.$imageFolder.$filename.'" alt="" />'; 
        $image .= '</a>'; 
        $image .= '</div>'; 
        echo $image; 
            if ($i > 1 && $i % 6  == 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';
        $i++; 
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: It got everyything laid out properly again, but now it's loading the whole folder instead of pagination

Comment: I just gave you the image layout code, you will have to redo the pagination

Comment: I'm not sure what to do, I'm just trying to piece this together from other peoples posting and what very little I know about php. What you posted looks pretty much identical to to gallery code I had originally.

Comment: I would suggest read and understand the code rather than just copying over.