# Pagination in PHP for image gallery that shows all images in folder

Tags: php, pagination, gallery

I am trying to add a pagination to my image gallery that I've made entirely in PHP.

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25704313/23556208) for it as it was the best fit I found.
However, browsing around I noticed that it's not working overall.

For example, I have a folder with 206 files and within 11 pages (18 per page) only shows 196 images.
I have another with 35 files and it doesn't go past the first page and so 18 images.

This is the code, where am I going wrong?
Please speak like I'm stupid because all of this I have done it's been out of my brain with no previous study or knowledge of PHP. Thanks

```
<div>
<?php
$folder = './././';
$filetype = '*.jpg*';    
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$total = count($files);    
$per_page = 18;    
$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);    
if(isset($_GET["page"])  && ($_GET["page"] <=$last_page) && ($_GET["page"] > 0) ){
    $page = $_GET["page"];
    $offset = ($per_page + 1)*($page - 1);      
}else{
    $page=1;
    $offset=0;      
}    
$max = $offset + $per_page;    
if($max>$total){
    $max = $total;
}
    
for ($i = $offset; $i< $max; $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $resolution = getimagesize($image);
        $file = $files[$i];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
        $filename = $path_parts['filename'];
        echo '<div class="thumbs">';
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$image.'"></a><br>';
        echo '<span class="thumb_size">' . strval($resolution[0]) . 'x' . strval($resolution[1]) . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
}   
show_pagination($page, $last_page); 
    
?>
</div>
<?php function show_pagination($current_page, $last_page){
    echo '<div class="pagination">';
    if( $current_page > 1 ){
        echo '<span class="button-14"><a href="?page='.($current_page-1).'"> &lt;&lt;Previous Page</a></span>&nbsp;';
    }
    if( $current_page < $last_page ){
        echo '<span class="button-14"><a href="?page='.($current_page+1).'"> Next Page&gt;&gt;</a></span>';  
    }
    echo '</div>';
}?>
```

Comment: `$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);` - casting to int doesn't do any rounding, it simply cuts off any decimals. With a total of 11 files and 10 per page, you would get `1` for $last_page here - but obviously, it should be `2`. You want `$last_page = ceil($total / $per_page);` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$last_page` is off by 1.  Consider what you're doing here:

```
$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);
```

If there's any remainder from that calculation, casting to `int` will drop that remainder.  So the last incomplete page of records is never available.

Instead of casting to an `int`, use [the `ceil()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php):

```
$last_page = ceil($total / $per_page);
```

That way if there's any remainder, even just a single extra record, the `$last_page` will always round *up* to account for that remainder.

Comment: Thanks @David, changing that one line helped to show the pagination on the folder of 35 files, but I don't understand if I'm expected to have 1 less image showing or not. Cause with that it's showing 34 instead of 35, and I didn't get if it's expected or not.

Comment: @LadyC: What specifically is "showing 34 instead of 35"?  If you're not familiar with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) then now is a great time to start.  Failing that, you could even find useful debugging information simply by outputting useful information to the page or to a log file, helping you see specifically what operations are producing what results.  When you do this, which specific operation is producing an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: among the many folders I tested this onto one has 35 images in it, but it's showing only 34 images after I changed that bit of code you told me before. Nothing else changed from my code above but that one line.

Comment: @LadyC: And when you debug, which of the many small operations shown in your code *first* produces an unexpected result?  Does `$files` have all of the files you expect?  Is `$total` the count of files you expect?  Does `$offset` get the value you expect?  Does `$max` get the value you expect?  How many times does that `for` loop iterate?  When you debug, which *specific* operation *first* fails?

Comment: I do not understand how I'm expected to debug, honestly

Comment: @LadyC: That's the more important problem to solve then, as debugging code (testing the code, observing specific runtime values and behaviors, etc.) is an essential part of writing code.  You can't do one without the other.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) is a reasonable place to start understanding what a debugger is and what it does.  If you're using an IDE to write and execute your code then you may have a debugger built in to that.  Alternatively, you could output useful information about your variables between operations just to see what they are.

Comment: adding this `echo "max: $max total: $total last_page: $last_page<br>";` to my code I got the output as `max: 18 total: 35 last_page: 2`, so it's counting the right number of total files, giving the right max of 18 per page and right count of pages that should be, which is 2.
I went one by one and in the jump from image #18 to image #20 when turning page, it seems like image #19 is lost somewhere, like it gets lost in the navigation button, if you know what I mean. I don't know how to do debugging and all, I read what you link but I don't get it, and it's too long for me as a dyslexic.

Comment: @LadyC: Take a look here: `$offset = ($per_page + 1)*($page - 1);`  If `$per_page` is `18`, and if `$page` is `2`, then `$offset` will be `19`.  And `$files[19]` is the 20th file.  Perhaps that `+ 1` is what's throwing off your calculations?

Answer (score 0):

*Two changes necessary for this coding to work*.

`$last_page = (int)($total / $per_page);`
into
`$last_page = ceil($total / $per_page);`

to allow me showing the pagination button even for one image remaining.

`$offset = ($per_page + 1)*($page - 1);` into `$offset = ($per_page)*($page - 1);`

not to have one image get lost in between switching pages and show them all.

*Full credits to David for helping in this.*